# Truncated tar archive error

Tags: ubuntu, tar

I am trying to untar a zip folder I downloaded of a Bioinformatics tool but I am repeatedly getting the truncated tar archive error. What am I doing wrong.
http://ncrna-pred.com/premiRNA.html

Click on the source code on this link and you will be able to download the tar file. I use ubuntu 14.04. Thank you.

Gave the command

> tar -xvzf HeteroMirPred.tar.gz

and got the error

> gzip: stdin: not in gzip format
>
> tar: Child returned status 1
>
> tar:Error is not recoverable: exiting now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The file has a `.gz` suffix but is not actually compressed.

You may check this with the `file` command:

```
$ file HeteroMirPred.tar.gz
HeteroMirPre.tar.gz: POSIX tar archive
```

Just drop the `z` from the flags to `tar`:

```
$ tar xvf HeteroMirPred.tar.gz
```

Answer (score 1):

That's not a tar file but a zipped tar. So make sure you are unzipping it correctly:

```
tar -xvzf HeteroMirPred.tar.gz
```

Comment: Gives me the error gzip: stdin: not in gzip format
tar: Child returned status 1
tar: Error is not recoverable: exiting now

Comment: It looks like the file was corrupted while you were downloading it. Works perfectly fine for me.

Comment: I don't know what the issue is that it isn't downloading properly for me.  I did it thrice before asking this question.  Could u please upload the unzipped file somewhere and send me a link